# My python script that i had tested and was working fine. Suddenly starts getting connection error

Tags: python

I wrote a few lines of python script to get links from my small site. I tested it, used it and was working fine but suddenly it starts generating connection error. I tried to use it on another site, it still generate same problem. I'm new to python, though. Help please!!! Thanks in advance
Part of the code and error message is as follow:

```
>>>import urllib,sgmllib

>>> f=urllib.urlopen("http://www.example.com")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 345, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 991, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 844, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 806, in send
    self.connect()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 787, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err

IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10061] No connection could be made becausethe target machine actively refused it
>>>
```

Comment: did you consider the possibility that the "target machine actively refused it" ? You may have been blocked.

Comment: Perhaps your public IP address has been blocked by the server(s) for violations of robots.txt. It is either that, or the server is not listening on port 80.

Comment: Sure seems like a legitimate error that Python is experiencing. Have you verified that access to the websites you've tested against is working from the computer this code is running on? Have you tried more than one test site that should be up, and should *not* be blocking your requests?

Comment: Yes. I tried other sites to test if I'm been blocked but not working too. I also used https port but not working. And i can access the sites with the computer the code is running on. Help Please!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Johan, Shashank, bmhkim for your contributions.
I just figured out the cause of the problem now and the solution. It was caused by the proxy setting of the host running the code. So, resetting the proxy solve it.